# Better way of extracting data from file for comparison

Tags: bash, sed, awk, diff

Problem: Comparison of files from Pre-check status and Post-check status of a node for specific parameters.

With some help from community, I have written the following solution which extracts the information from files from directories pre and post and based on the "Node-ID" (which happens to be unique  and is to be extracted from the files as well). After extracting the data from Pre/post folder, I have created folders based on the node-id and dumped files into the folders.

My Code to extract data (The data is extracted from Pre and Post folders)

```
FILES=$(find postcheck_logs -type f -name *.log)
for f in $FILES
do
    NODE=`cat $f | grep -m 1 ">" | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/[>]//g'`  ##Generate the node-id
    echo "Extracting Post check information for " $NODE 
    mkdir temp/$NODE-post  ## create a temp directory
    cat $f | awk 'BEGIN { RS=$NODE"> "; } /^param1/ { foo=RS $0; } END { print foo ; }' > temp/$NODE-post/param1.txt ## extract data
    cat $f | awk 'BEGIN { RS=$NODE"> "; } /^param2/ { foo=RS $0; } END { print foo ; }' > temp/$NODE-post/param2.txt
    cat $f | awk 'BEGIN { RS=$NODE"> "; } /^param3/ { foo=RS $0; } END { print foo ; }' > temp/$NODE-post/param3.txt
done
```

After this I have a structure as:

```
/Node1-pre/param1.txt
/Node1-post/param1.txt
```

and so on.

Now I am stuck to compare `$NODE-pre` and `$NODE-post` files,

I have tried to do it using recursive grep, but I am not finding a suitable way to do so. What is the best possible way to compare these files using diff?

Moreover, I find the above data extraction program very slow. I believe it's not the best possible way (using least resources) to do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain which Pre and Post files are you talking about, or give some examples?

Comment: The pre and post file contains output from a node. For example, 
node-id> command 
[Output]
node-id> command 2
[Output]

Comment: What is "Node" in your context?

Comment: Node can be any system/machine the person is working upon, we generate some system logs working on that system. The logs have same format( but the output of commands are always different) the node can be considered something similar to the bash prompt but with a trailing '>'

Comment: Can you give some example of input and expected output?

Comment: Considering the massive amount of Useless Uses of Cat and `grep | awk | sed` pipelines, this is certainly not optimal. But if performance is an issue, a more radical refactoring may be called for. Anyway, visit http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: Upon closer inspection, using three separate awk scripts means you process each input file three times. Are the files large? Anyway, an equivalent single awk script should be trivial to write.

Comment: @tripleee  the problem is i need to scan files 3 times as i have to ouput different type of data based on different commands to seperate files for comparison

Comment: @igustin i have solved the problem for data extraction , but i am not sure how to make diff work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look askance at any instance of `cat one-file` — you could use I/O redirection on the next command in the pipeline instead.

You can do the whole thing more simply with:

```
for f in $(find postcheck_logs -type f -name *.log)
do
    NODE=$(sed '/>/{ s/ .*//; s/>//g; p; q; }' $f)  ##Generate the node-id
    echo "Extracting Post check information for $NODE" 
    mkdir temp/$NODE-post
    awk -v NODE="$NODE" -v DIR="temp/$NODE-post" \
        'BEGIN { RS=NODE"> " }
         /^param1/ { param1 = $0 }
         /^param2/ { param2 = $0 }
         /^param3/ { param3 = $0 }
         END {
             print RS param1 > DIR "/param1.txt"
             print RS param2 > DIR "/param2.txt"
             print RS param3 > DIR "/param3.txt"
             }' $f
done
```

The NODE finding process is much better done by a single `sed` command than `cat | grep | awk | sed`, and you should plan to use `$(...)` rather than back-quotes everywhere.

The main processing of the log file should be done once; a single `awk` command is sufficient.  The script is passed to variables — NODE and the directory name.  The BEGIN is cleaned up; the `$` before NODE was probably not what you intended.  The main actions are very similar; each looks for the relevant parameter name and saves it in an appropriate variable.  At the end, it write the saved values to the relevant files, decorated with the value of RS.  Semicolons are only needed when there's more than one statement on a line; there's just one statement per line in this expanded script.  It looks bigger than the original, but that's only because I'm using vertical space.

---

As to comparing the before and after files, you can do it in many ways, depending on what you want to know.  If you've got a POSIX-compliant `diff` (you probably do), you can use:

```
diff -r temp/$NODE-pre temp/$NODE-post
```

to report on the differences, if any, between the contents of the two directories.  Alternatively, you can do it manually:

```
for file in param1.txt param2.txt param3.txt
do
    if cmp -s temp/$NODE-pre/$file temp/$NODE-post/$file
    then : No difference
    else diff temp/$NODE-pre/$file temp/$NODE-post/$file
    fi
done
```

Clearly, you can wrap that in a 'for each node' loop.  And, if you are going to need to do that, then you probably do want to capture the output of the `find` command in a variable (as in the original code) so that you do not have to repeat that operation.

Comment: I believe the above code will not only compare node1-pre and node1-post but it will compare Node1-pre with other nodes posts also.